# How can I align an item with an item above it in html/css/js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 3 input blanks on my form (see the screenshot below). I have 1 dropdown button and one `<input type="text">` in 1 row and another `<input type="text">` in the 2nd row. I want the 2 `<input type="text">` to align. In other words, I want the "Choice 2" box to be right below the "Choice 1" box. How can I do this? Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

By the way, This is my html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        2
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul id="list" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      </ul>
      <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 1"> <br>
</div>
<div class="container">
<input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 2">
    </div></div>
```

And this is my css:

```
.container {padding: 1% 20%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;}

body {
  background-color: #b6e6bd;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
```

How can I make the choice 1 and choice 2 boxes which are both `<input type="text">` be directly above and below each other? Thanks

Comment: **N.B.** It's a _text input_ or an `<input type="text">` - it's not a "text input button".

Comment: Also, I believe you are using Bootstrap, right? Because otherwise your code doesn't work the way you said it would.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 Yes N.B. Ok will change

Comment: This source result is not equal the image you sent! Please send the right source to help better.

Comment: @MostafaKalantariFard Sorry now it's correct, made a change in html

Comment: @argonx please add snippet with bootstrap script for simplicity

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are allowed to slightly change HTML?

Here is my try. I've moved two `input[text]` to one `div` and the dropdown to another. Also I changed `.container` class to be `flex@center` (but you can use any other layout - `table` or `div` with known widths).

```css
.container {
  padding: 1% 20%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #b6e6bd;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.container-inner {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        2
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
    <ul id="list" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container-inner">
    <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 1"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a framework like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). But if you won't I suggest you to change your code to this:

```css
.container {
    padding: 1% 20%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;}

body {
    background-color: #b6e6bd;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            2
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <select id="list" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <option><a href="#">2</a></option>
            <option><a href="#">3</a></option>
            <option><a href="#">4</a></option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 1"> <br>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 2" style="margin-right: -64px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will helpful.

Comment: That should work, I understand the logic...but somehow choice 2 is too much to the right if I do this, but thanks for the idea